# How to get text of a label using for

Tags: jquery, label

How can I get the text of a label via the `for` selector? Here's my label:

```
<label for="startdate">Iteration Start</label>
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
$("label[for='startdate']").text();
```

But this returns "".

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
alert($('label[for=startdate]').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="startdate">Iteration Start</label>
```

Use [attr selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.